# Integrate Multiple Shiro Realms into a Spring Boot environment Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shiro

I have a xml based Apache Shiro SecurityManager and few custom realms (They extend build in realms). I am trying to migrate to Spring Boot, which is mostly annotation based.

I want to configure ALL realms into the security manager easily.Currently, I am able to do it by creating a ShiroConfig.java (annotated by @Configuration) , manually creating the object of each realm in the ShiroConfig and adding it under DefaultWebSecurityManager.setRealms(Collection).

**Is there any other way, by which same thing can be achieved by annotation, where I annotate each Realm ,saying it's a realm and all of them will be added under security manager at runtime ?**

- Current xml configuration

  `<bean id="securityManager" class="com.abc.xyz.SecurityManager">
          <property name="realms">
              <set>
                  <ref component-id="Realm_1”/> 
                  <ref component-id="Realm_2” />
                  <ref component-id="Realm_3” />
                  <ref component-id="Realm_4” />
              </set>
          </property>
      </bean>
   <bean id="Realm_1" class="com.abc.xyz.Realm_1”>
          </bean>
       <bean id="Realm_2" class="com.abc.xyz.Realm_2”>
          </bean>
       <bean id="Realm_3” class="com.abc.xyz.Realm_3”>
          </bean>
       <bean id="Realm_4” class="com.abc.xyz.Realm_4”>
          </bean>`

  - Current Spring boot code [which I don't want to repeat for each realm]

@Bean(name="securityManager")

```
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager() {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager manager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    manager.setRealm(userRealm());
    manager.setSessionManager(defaultWebSessionManager());
    return manager;
}
```

@Bean
    @DependsOn(value="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")

```
public Realm_1 userRealm() {
    Realm_1 userRealm = new Realm_1();
    return userRealm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shiro 1.4 is hot off the presses, we are working on getting the site updated now. But take a look at the examples, you can just inject your Realms in Spring and Spring-Boot.

https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/support/spring/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/spring/config/ShiroConfiguration.java#L44-L48

https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/master/samples/spring/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/samples/spring/CliApp.java#L46-L56

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however my question is more on , if I have 4 realms ,can by some annotations they can be injected into the security manager ,rather then me manually creating a list of realms and passing to the security manager as the below code snippet in your first ShiroConfiguratin.java file
     ` @ Bean
     @ Override
     protected SessionsSecurityManager securityManager(List<Realm> realms) {
         return super.securityManager(realms);
     }`

Comment: You should be able to expose your beans just like you would for any of your other Spring beans.